# Reachability - Check if valid with connection on public Wi-Fi

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, reachability

I am currently using an adapted reachabilty framework based on Apple's sample code.

The framework works fine, however it provides false postives.

If the user is attached to a wifi network where they are required to login before having a valid connection, the framework shows as an active connection when in fact it isn't.

An example of this is Starbucks' wifi where you must provide an email address before you get online.

Is there a way around this without pinging a certain address?

Currently I am using the `reachabilityWithHostname` function

Thanks

Daniel

Update as provided by the link below i see this is a limitation of the framework. Are others finding away to alert the user of this?

> If your computer is connected to a Wi-Fi access point, but that access point's internet connection is down, reachability will tell you that yes, you have a network connection

Comment: Access a url and see if you get a bit of data or more.

Comment: Issue with this is you will always return he login html page data. Also there is a delay in doing so (You have to wait for it to time out)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [link](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-06-14-reachability.html)

> Networking is playing an ever more important role in application
>   development, and Apple's reachability API is a valuable tool in making
>   network-centric apps play nicely with varying real-world conditions.
>   Today I'm going to give an overview of the reachability API, what it
>   does, and how to use it.

This should help you.

Comment: As per this document i take it its a limitation, however i wondered if others have a work around